# Matching two dictionaries in python(cross match)

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I have two dictionaries A and B. I would like to match the **values** of dictionary **A** with the **keys** of dictionary **B**. If they match, I would like to get the **values** of dictionary **B**.

The problem is that the values of dictionary A are in a list.

```
A={'x':['corn','apple'],'y':['coconut','apple']}

B={'corn':6, 'pineapple':7,'apple':8}
```

The final output should look like this

```
output= {'x':6, 'x':8, 'y':8}
```

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: your output has repeated keys which doesn't make sense for dictionaries. Would tuples suffice?

Comment: Yes, tuples would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries can only have unique keys.

Perhaps you meant `output= {'x': [6, 8], 'y':[8]}`?

If so, you can do this:

```
output = {a_key: [B[value] for value in A[a_key] if value in B] for a_key in A.keys()}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following should give you what you want with a little nested list comprehension

```
output = [(k, B[v]) for k in A for v in A[k] if v in B]
```

Result

```
[('y', 8), ('x', 6), ('x', 8)]
```